# How do I calculate the ratio of two values within a SQL group?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My input is:
[image]

My desired output is:
[image]

I am unable to figure out how to calculate the ratio for cash-to-coupons quantities for both rows belonging to that particular item.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: `I am unable to figure out how to calculate the ratio for cash-to-coupons quantities for both rows belonging to that particular item`. So does I. Maybe you can provide the calculation method on how to obtain those figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example**

```
Select * 
      ,Ratio = convert(decimal(10,2),
               sum(case when [Payment_Mode]='Cash' then [Quantity]+0.0 end) over (Partition By [Item])
              /sum(case when [Payment_Mode]='Coupons' then [Quantity]  end) over (Partition By [Item])
              )
 From YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Item    Payment_Mode    Quantity    Ratio
Apples  Cash            20          2.00
Apples  Coupons         10          2.00
Grapes  Cash            45          15.00
Grapes  Coupons         3           15.00
Oranges Cash            300         20.00
Oranges Coupons         15          20.00
```

**EDIT - Another Option is with a simple Join and a conditional aggregation**

```
Select A.*
      ,B.Ratio
 From  YourTable A
 Join  (
        Select Item
              ,Ratio = sum(case when [Payment_Mode]='Cash'  then [Quantity]+0.0 end) /NullIF(sum(case when [Payment_Mode]='Coupons' then [Quantity] end),0)
         From  YourTable
         Group By Item
       ) B  on A.Item=B.Item
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `max` as a window function.

```
select t.*,
       1.0*max(case when payment = 'Cash' then Payment end) over(partition by Item) / 
       max(case when payment = 'Coupon' then Payment end) over(partition by Item)
from tbl t
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully formatted:

```
SELECT  ix.Item,
    ix.Seq,
    ix.Payment_Mode,
    ix.Quantity,
    ix.PrevQuantity,
    ix.NextQuantity,
    CASE WHEN ix.PrevQuantity = 0 THEN ix.Quantity/ix.NextQuantity ELSE ix.PrevQuantity/ix.Quantity END [Ratio]
FROM
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                (
                    PARTITION BY
                        i.Item
                    ORDER BY i.Item, i.Payment_Mode
                ) AS Seq,
            i.Item,
            i.Payment_Mode,
            i.Quantity,
            LEAD(Quantity, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY i.Item ORDER BY i.Item ASC) AS NextQuantity,
            LAG(Quantity, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY i.Item ORDER BY i.Item ASC) AS PrevQuantity
    FROM    #ITEMS i
) AS ix
```

Comment: Obviously #ITEMS is a temp table I created to contain the data presented in the original question.

Comment: Ignore ROW_NUMBER not required